# Trouble removing hidden parts of a string

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use a scraped `string` with `BeautifulSoup` in a simple calculation. The interpreter gives a `base 10 error`, indicating that there's hidden characters in the string.

This turned out to be true, because the console outputs the raw string including hidden data as:

```
2.177
['\n\n2.177']
```

`2.177` is the number I'm trying to work with here. `['\n\n2.177']` is a hidden part of the string.  Since it won't cast to int because of the hidden values however I can't make any calculations on it.

I've looked up a few ways to remove hidden characters from strings but so far stackoverflow only seems to have answers regarding removing special hidden characters.

Mine are sadly not special. Does anyone know how to remove this part of the string?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what the value of the string is, by example?
e.g. `print("2.177 ['\\n\\n2.177']")`

Comment: Sure. I'll show you. So the string, called "vacancy_amount" is obtained after a few splits so that i could get just the number from the sentence. Now one printline prints out the right value: `print(vacancy_amount)` prints out 2177. However `print([vacancy_amount])` gives me 2.177 ['\n\n2.177'], showing that there are hidden characters in the string which blocks me from casting it to an int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the clarification, it looks like the contents of the string are `"\n\n2.177"`, i.e. with two leading newline characters. In this case, the issue is not so much with the newlines as the fact that `2.177` is indeed not a valid representation of an `int`. Both `int("\n\n2.177")` and `int("2.177")` give `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '2.177'`.

To answer your direct question, you can strip leading and trailing whitespace with the `strip` method on strings, e.g. `vacancy_amount.strip()`.

Perhaps instead you intend to get a floating-point number out, in which case `float(vacancy_amount)` will give you `2.177`. If you want to further convert this to an integer, you can try `int(float(vacancy_amount))` to give `2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions:

```
import re
s = '\n\n2.177'
new_s = re.findall('[\.\d]+', s)
```

Output:

```
['2.177']
```